# How to stack ReaderT and WriterT transformers in scalaz?

Tags: scala, scalaz

I'm playing with monad transformers in `scalaz`. I'm trying to stack together a Writer on the top of Reader with the underlying `Id` monad. For combining them I'm using `MonadReader` and `MonadWriter` type classes.

I managed to compile and run the following code sample **without** the writer (i.e. with the `Reader` monad, i.e. `ReaderT[Id.Id, String, A]`). When adding a `WriterT` to the stack, I get the compilation error:

```
Gist.scala:10: could not find implicit value for parameter F: scalaz.MonadReader[Gist.R,String]
   val MR = MonadReader[R, String]
                       ^
```

How can I obtain an instance of `MonadReader` for my transformer stack? Do I have to make use of `ReaderWriterStateT` or is there another way?

Full code:

```
import scalaz.{Id, MonadListen, MonadReader, ReaderT, WriterT}

object Gist {
  import scalaz.std.list._
  import scalaz.syntax.monad._

  type P[A] = ReaderT[Id.Id, String, A]
  type R[A] = WriterT[P, List[String], A]

  val MR = MonadReader[R, String]
  val MW = MonadListen[R, List[String]]

  def apply: R[String] = MR.ask >>= { greeting =>
    MW.tell(List(s"greeting $greeting")) >>= { _ =>
      MW.point(s"Hello $greeting")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why Scalaz doesn't provide this instance (or `MonadReader` instances for similar monad transformers), but I'd guess the answer has something to do with the fact that `WriterTInstanceN` already [goes past 11](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/v7.2.10/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/WriterT.scala#L106) and adding in `MonadReader` would just make things even more of a mess.

You could dig around in Scalaz's GitHub issues (or even ask on the IRC channel if you have the stomach for that kind of thing), but I'm not sure the answer matters all that much.

You can pretty straightforwardly port the instance from Haskell's [mtl](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/src/Control.Monad.Reader.Class.html#line-167):

```
instance (Monoid w, MonadReader r m) => MonadReader r (Strict.WriterT w m) where
    ask   = lift ask
    local = Strict.mapWriterT . local
    reader = lift . reader
```

Which translated into Scala looks like this:

```
import scalaz.{ MonadReader, MonadTrans, Monoid, WriterT }
import scalaz.syntax.monad._

implicit def monadReaderForWriterT[F[_], I, W](implicit
  F: MonadReader[F, I],
  W: Monoid[W]
): MonadReader[WriterT[F, W, ?], I] = new MonadReader[WriterT[F, W, ?], I] {
  def ask: WriterT[F, W, I] = MonadTrans[WriterT[?[_], W, ?]].liftM(F.ask)

  def local[A](f: I => I)(fa: WriterT[F, W, A]): WriterT[F, W, A] =
    fa.mapT(F.local(f))

  def point[A](a: => A): WriterT[F, W, A] = a.point[WriterT[F, W, ?]]
  def bind[A, B](fa: WriterT[F, W, A])(
    f: A => WriterT[F, W, B]
  ): WriterT[F, W, B] = fa.flatMap(f)
}
```

Note that I'm using [kind-projector](https://github.com/non/kind-projector), since the type lambda version would be more like four or five times as long as the Haskell version instead of just three times.

Once you've defined this instance, you can write the following:

```
import scalaz.{ Id, MonadListen, ReaderT }
import scalaz.std.list._

type P[A] = ReaderT[Id.Id, String, A]
type R[A] = WriterT[P, List[String], A]

val MR = MonadReader[R, String]
val MW = MonadListen[R, List[String]]

def apply: R[String] = MR.ask >>= { greeting =>
  MW.tell(List(s"greeting $greeting")) >>= { _ =>
    MW.point(s"Hello $greeting")
  }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. For teaching purpose, can you think of another transformer stack/type class combination without `scalaz` implementation, so I can practice writing my own implementation?

Comment: @mgryszko You can see the list for Haskell's mtl [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Reader-Class.html)—`StateT`, `ListT`, `ContT`, `EitherT`, `IdT`, etc. are all good candidates.